# Looping data in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I get the value `BrandName` in this image using javascript loop.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED:** Since `data` variable you use to display the response is already a `CartObject` then use:

```
for (var i = 0, len = data.CartLists.length; i < len; i++) {
    console.log( data.CartLists[i].Item.BrandName );
}
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined ` error.

Comment: @Domo Are you sure that variable `CartObject` exists?

Comment: Yeah sure VisioN. Anyway I did `console.log(data);` to print out the object in the console image above.

Comment: @Domo Aha! Since the root element is `data`, then you need to use `data.CartObject ...` instead.

Comment: After adding `data` then `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'CartLists' of undefined` :/

Comment: @Domo Then please show the rest of your code otherwise we are not able to identify the problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39258/discussion-between-domo-and-vision)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the one VisioN said is the following:

```
for (var CartItemId in CartObject.CartLists) {
     Console.log(CartObject.CartLists[CartItemId].Item.BrandName);
}
```

However, If you would attach an Prototype to the JSON object, you could obtain an Object in the for-loop instead of an Integer (Number).

```
for (var CartItem in CartObject.CarLists) {
     Console.log(CartItem.Item.BrandName);
}
```

Note that if you are going to make everything right, you should insert the following in the for-loop:

```
if (CartObject.CarLists.hasOwnProperty(CartItem)) {
    Console.log(CartItem.Item.BrandName);
}
```

---

This example will work, but as seen in the comments below. The use of it is not what it is designed for. The For-In loop is designed to loop over Object properties, not Array items.

Comment: [It is always better to loop arrays using plain `for` loop instead of `for .. in` loop.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3010848/1249581)

Comment: In my opinion it doesn't really matter aslong you include the 'hasOwnProperty' method.

Comment: Meaning that it is faster and easier to use 'numeric' iteration `=)`.

Comment: True, but it is an alternative. Next to this, the for..in might be of wrong use in here. Its looping through an array, not the properties. It will work, but it is not what for..in is designed for.